# Cordova navigate from remote page back to local

Tags: cordova

Have cordova app, with content on index html.
So i need show some page on remote web site (my own) and then go back to local page. I'm try file:///android_asset/www/index.html, but nothing happend.
Try "a href", window.open, what i do wrong?

Comment: why not use History.back()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i don't now actual count of redirects.
i solve this problem using inappbrowser